# How to use from_json standard function with custom schema (error: overloaded method value from_json with alternative)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am consuming JSON data from AWS Kinesis stream, but I am getting the following error when I try to use the `from_json()` standard function:

```
command-5804948:32: error: overloaded method value from_json with alternatives:
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
    .select(from_json("jsonData", dataSchema).as("devices"))
```

I have tried both of the below to define my schema:

```
val dataSchema = new StructType()
        .add("ID", StringType)
        .add("Type", StringType)
        .add("Body", StringType)
        .add("Submitted", StringType)

val dataSchema = StructType(Seq(StructField("ID",StringType,true), StructField("Type",StringType,true), StructField("Body",StringType,true), StructField("Submitted",StringType,true)))
```

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import scala.util.Random

val dataSchema = new StructType()
        .add("ID", StringType)
        .add("Type", StringType)
        .add("Body", StringType)
        .add("Submitted", StringType)

// val dataSchema = StructType(Seq(StructField("ID",StringType,true), StructField("Type",StringType,true), StructField("Body",StringType,true), StructField("Submitted",StringType,true)))

val kinesisDF = spark.readStream
    .format("kinesis")
    .option("streamName", "**************************")
    .option("region", "********")
    .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
    .option("awsAccessKey", "****************")
    .option("awsSecretKey", "************************************")
    .load()

val schemaDF = kinesisDF
    .selectExpr("cast (data as STRING) jsonData")
    .select(from_json("jsonData", dataSchema).as("devices"))
    .select("devices.*")
    .load()

display(schemaDF)
```

If you do the following:

```
val str_data = kinesisDF
    .selectExpr("cast (data as STRING) jsonData")

display(str_data)
```

you can see that the stream data looks like:

{"ID":"1266ee3d99bc-96f942a6-434c-6442-a762","Type":"BT","Body":"{\"TN\":\"ND\",\"TD\":\"JSON:{\\"vw\\":\\"CV\\"}\",\"LT\":\"BT\",\"TI\":\"9ff2-4749250dd142-793ffb20-eb8e-47f7\",\"CN\":\"OD\",\"CI\":\"eb\",\"UI\":\"abc004\",\"AN\":\"1234567\",\"TT\":\"2019-09-15T09:48:25.0395209Z\",\"FI\":\"N/A\",\"HI\":\"N/A\",\"SV\":6}","Submitted":"2019-09-15 09:48:26.079"}

{"ID":"c8eb956ee98c-68d668b7-e7a6-9ea2-49a5","Type":"MS","Body":"{\"MT\":\"N/A\",\"EP\":\"N/A\",\"RQ\":\"{\\"IA]\\":false,\\"AN\\":null,\\"ACI\\":\\"1266ee3d99bc-96f942a6-434c-6442-a762\\",\\"CI\\":\\"ebb\\",\\"CG\\":\\"8b8a-4ab17555f2fa-da0c8047-b5a6-4ebe\\",\\"UI\\":\\"def211\\",\\"UR\\":\\"EscC\\",\\"UL\\":\\"SCC\\",\\"TI\\":\\"b9d2-d4f646a15d66-dc519f4a-48c3-4e7b\\",\\"TN\\":null,\\"MN\\":null,\\"CTZ\\":null,\\"PM\\":null,\\"TS\\":null,\\"CI\\":\\"ebc\\",\\"ALDC\\":null}","Submitted":"2019-09-15 09:49:46.901"}

The value for the "Body" key is another JSON/nested JSON that is why I have put it as a StringType in the schema so that gets stored in the column as is. 
I get the following error when I run the above code:

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the error says it all:

> cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)

That means that there are three different alternatives of `from_json` standard function, and all of them expect a `Column` object not a `String`.

You can simply fix it by using `$` syntax (or using `col` standard function) as follows:

```
.select(from_json($"jsonData", dataSchema).as("devices"))
```

Note the `$` before the column name that turns it (implicitly) into a `Column` object.